# Is it safe to do Pranava Yog (Chanting Om) without guidance or Guru?

Tags: meditation, om, pranava-yoga

Is it safe to do [Pranava Yog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pranava_yoga) wich is Chanting [Om](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Om) without guidance or Guru?

Is there any side effect of doing alone by just reading on internet and for random duration?